# VIEWS and Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

It's possible to map a VIEW using Fluent NHibernate? If so, how?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would think you could just replace your the table name with your view name using the WithTable method:

```
WithTable("myview");
```

**Edit:** Just to update this answer, Fluent NHibernate now uses:

```
Table("myview");
```

Comment: What if this view doesn't have any primary key?

Answer (score 3):

mxmissile's answer is correct but I wanted to add that the view will have to be updateable (SQL Server term.) if you want to do inserts or updates against it. I have several tables mapped against views that filter out inactive records because these tables allow soft deletes.

Comment: If I recall, these "updateable" views are title Indexed Views?  It's been awhile since I had to deal with this stuff.